# Why does Select by Location select points outside search radius?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, select-by-location

I'm using Select by Location to find wind turbines within 5-km of a center point feature -- why does this command also select nearby turbines?

The image below shows my selected points with a 5-km buffer circle drawn for comparison. As you can see, turbines that are not even close to touching the circle are included.

[image]

Comment: Are both in the same spatial reference? Are you trying to select geographic features with a projected circle or the other way around? In the select by location dialog have you got the 'buffer' checked?

Comment: Are they single points or multi-points (or multipart features)? What coordinate systems are you working with *data layers and data frame)? Version of ArcGIS? Using Cartesian or Geodedic distances/buffers? I suspect it's a simple you're in geographic coordinates and need to be in a projected coordinate system.

Comment: I think either of the above comments could lead to these symptoms so I think we need you to **edit** your question and provide precise details of the steps you take from starting ArcMap and adding in the data - with details of where the data is stored and in what coordinate system.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: Both are in the same projection (North_America_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic). I don't see a buffer option in the Select by Location dialog. I have it set as "select features from" MY TARGET LAYER, Source layer: MY SOURCE, Spatial selection method...: "are within a distance of the source layer feature", Apply a search distance: 5000 meters.

Comment: Using ArcMap 10.2 and following the procedure detailed in my above comment. Data layers are stored as Shapefiles, both with the same PCS. However, I do note that my Data Frame is using "USA_Contiguous_Equidistant_Conic".

Comment: That could be it, to keep things uniform the selection is done in the coordinate system of the data frame. Try changing the spatial reference to match the data. Can you confirm that they're not MulitPoint features? If this problem persists you can use a tool like Near (advanced license) or Generate Near table (again advanced license) to determine the distance of each point to the closest (or all) wind farm points then select by attributes (NEAR_DIST < 5000)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions re coordinate systems. They are not multipoint features. Thanks!

Comment: Yo -- thanks for the thoughts about projects. I changed the data frame's PCS to match the Layer's PCS (N America Albers) and it now seems to work much more accurately. Thanks Stackers!

Comment: I think @MichaelMiles-Stimson should make the answer here. It's worth noting that you were performing the selections/buffers in a projected CRS, but while your data was in equal area which was fine, the equidistant of the dataframe is not. In an equidistant projection, distances are only accurate from one or two specific points to all other points - but *not* from any point to any other point. And radouxju's answer gives example to why it's best to **edit** your question, using the link at the lower left corner, than just leave clarifying information only in comments where it can be missed.

Comment: It sounds like you know more about these coordinate systems @ChrisW and their limitations, I think you should compile an answer.

Answer (score 1):

"multi-points" (you can check in the geometry field) behave like single geometries. You can convert from multi-point to points using "[multipart to single part](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003r000000)" tool, then you can run your "select by location" within a distance. If needed, you can then [dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Dissolve/00170000005n000000/) the points based on the original ORIG_ID in order to reconstruct the multi-points.

The other option is to create the buffers around your wind farm, then [intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000) with your multi-points (the output will be multi-points).